# Published History of Harvard

Tags: book, reference

Is anyone aware of a modern, single-volume published history of Harvard University? There seem to be numerous such histories for Oxford and Cambridge (admittedly, older institutions) but I haven't been able to find one for Harvard.

Comment: Have you checked [History of Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Harvard_University#References) references?

Comment: Try "The Founding of Harvard College", by the Pulitzer prize winning historian, Samuel Eliot Morrison.  This Amazon page lists other histories of Harvard which will bring you to the present: https://smile.amazon.com/Founding-Harvard-College-foreword-Hawkins/dp/0674314514/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because request for references are explicitly off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search yielded the following: The history of Harvard University. By Josiah Quincy. Under the Amazon listing for this book are other titles relating to the history of Harvard. I suggest you hone your search skills.

Comment: I believe that is a two-volume history, published in the early 19th century. [Volume 1](https://archive.org/stream/historyharvardu03quingoog#page/n8/mode/2up) and [Volume 2](https://archive.org/stream/historyharvardu06quingoog#page/n5/mode/2up)

Comment: I'm willing to stretch the definition of a modern history, but 1840 is pushing it a bit. Not that it is super important, but  Quincy's work is also a two volume history.